# how to check string contain emailid or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

i m looking for checking emailid in content of message body.
i do not want to allow any one to send message that contain email address as a part of message.

so how can i achieve this in asp.net c#??

Please help me if any one has an idea about this !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+@([A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.)+([A-Za-z\-])+");
MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(Text);
foreach (Match s in matches)
{//do whatever with s.Value}
```